# possible to call other model through foreign key in templates? django

Tags: python, django, templates, model

let's say I have two models

```
class T(models.Model):
    name = model.Charfield(max_length=12)

class S(models.Model):
    tt = model.ForeignKey(T)
    boo = model.Boolean(default=False)
```

when I use this...`t_objs= T.objects.all()` then in my template I know I can loop and use

```
{% for t in t_objs %}
    {{t.name}}
```

and so on....but what if I want to get how many I can use `t_objs` to find how many `S` each `t` has and also pull out info of `S`

is this possible though?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "backward relation" between S and T by doing something like `t.s_set.all():`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

This can be accessed from the template as well:

```
{% for t in t_objs %}
    {{t.name}}
    {% for s in t.s_set.all %}
      {{ s.boo }}
    {% endfor %}
    <p>The total count of S for this T is {{ t.s_set|length }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```